# Development architecture for Website hosted on own server

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

[image]

I have developed simple websites and hosted them on shared networks, mainly godaddy. So, i never came across the issue of having a server OS and other things related with self hosting.

Above, i have tried to make a flow chart of architecture, software stack or technologies, whatever you say, to understand what really is required.

**Please correct me if my understanding is wrong**

***Also, tell me if there is any framework available for fast development in PHP, like .NET is there for C#. Or is it just on the go language(PHP)***

Comment: There are hundreds of webservers, hundreds of frameworks, and 10s of web development languages. There are also hundreds of OS's but non-mainstream OS's are unpopular to use.

Comment: Though you have asked for useful information, but try to stick to one point per question and ask something which can be directly addressed.

Comment: i don't know why the moderators are so keen on closing a question so fast. I know this might have been close to some other questions but slightly different views from other users can help me learn thing on a particular topic

Comment: .NET is not a Framework for Fast C# development!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are lots of frameworks for PHP (and pretty much every language):

http://codeigniter.com/

http://cakephp.org/

http://framework.zend.com/

There are many others: http://www.phpframeworks.com/

Comment: Some people would consider those frameworks to be evil or poorly designed.

Comment: Well, they are written in PHP, after all.